# Get updated data in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I try to fetch data using `useEffect`. Trying this I get many renders in the fetching process.

Ex:

First render:

```
data = []
```

Second render:

```
data = [{...}{...}]
```

So the data array is populated just after 2 renders. Why? and how to get data rendered in the first render?

Comment: The only way to get async data on the first render is to move the data fetching into a parent, and delay rendering of the child until it is present. Otherwise, just deal with the extra renders, if your data is initialized correctly, it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: please add your code or a snippet of what you've tried

Comment: The `useEffect` is called when the variables in the dependency array are changed. So if they get changed in the second render then the data is also changed in the second render

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting your data in `useEffect` there are going to be extra renders when the data has not been loaded yet. But generally you should not be worried by this as renders are pretty fast.

Only way to get around this is to load the data in some parent component and then pass it to the child component as param. This way you can have a component with non-trivial render of data, that will be displayed by parent only when data are already available